# How to check if a specific field contains an error in Django

Tags: python, django

How do you check if a specific form field contains an error in a Django view?

I have a sign up form and when a username throws an error I would like to display a flash message at the top of the page with the error.

Basically something along the lines of:

```
if username_field in form has errors:
  messages.warning(request, "...")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get form errors as python dict, just `your_form.errors`

```
if username_field in your_form.errors:
    messages.warning(request, "...")
```

Comment: This is just a code snippet - no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: yeah, but the author doesn't know how you fixed it

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I added it.

Comment: you ended up in the review queue